# Xamarin UWP: App is not getting suspended when switching to another app

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms

I have created an app using Xamarin Forms. When we open another app, then the suspended event is not getting called in UWP. Suspended event is getting called only when we minimize the app.

Comment: Is this on Windows desktop OS? If so, this is the expected behavior for an app. The user expects your app to keep running when it looses focus.

Comment: Yes, it is happening on windows 10. But in windows 8.1 the suspended event is getting called.

Comment: In Windows 8.1 you are running in the equivalent of the Windows 10 tablet mode (i.e. single window environment vs multi-window environment). On Windows 10 if you switch to tablet mode in the settings and then test again you should see the suspend event getting fired as well when you launch another app.